# What is the Difference between difference between Standard Electrode Potentials and Standard Reduction Potentials?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis, reduction-potential

As the question suggests I am wondering the **difference** between standard electrode potentials and standard reduction potentials. I know that they are **both a measure of the Voltage** from certain reactions, and can be used to calculate the **feasibility** of a reaction - but when do you use which / what is the difference, or are they **interchangeable**?

Comment: Are they not the same thing? Do you have specific data which suggests they are different?

Comment: Well in a data booklet (such as: https://www.scribd.com/doc/16633801/GCE-Chemistry-Data-Booklet-Issue-2 , Page 14-17), they are it separate sections, with one being 'Electrode Reaction' and the other being 'Right-hand electrode system'.

Comment: They appear to be exactly the same except that one page lists reduction equations and their potentials whereas the other page just lists the species being reduced and the species formed and leaves you to work out the equation.